# In docusign , i can't see connect option for webhook with live credential

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks, docusigncompositetmplts

Please, can you suggest me, how I integrate connect for webhook with my live credentials?
I have already integrated a webhook in my sandbox account.
I can't see connect option with login my live credential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DocuSign Production account doesn't have the option for Connect, you may need to reach out to your Account Manager to have that enabled.

Answer (score 0):

All DocuSign account plans that include API access include envelope-specific webhook.

An envelope-specific webhook is set using the `eventNotification` attribute when an envelope is created via the API.

Some DocuSign account plans include account-level webhooks (Custom Connect configurations). Those are set via the admin tool. As Drew says, talk with your account manager if account-level webhooks are not shown on your admin tool.